# How can I stop moving object when I touch to object?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

My game app has randomly moving object. I want to stop that and print some words on the screen when I touch/catch that. But I don't know what can I do this in gamescene.swift page. What should I write in touchesBegan? Here is my code :

```
import SpriteKit

let BallCategoryName = "ball"

class GameScene: SKScene {
   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       super.didMoveToView(view)

       let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)


       borderBody.friction = 0


       self.physicsBody = borderBody


       physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(15, 15)

       let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
       ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

 }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

       let touch = touches.first as! UITouch


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put the variable ball outside didMoveToView:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

touchesBegan:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches{
        let location = (touch as! UITouch).locationInNode(self)
        let nodeTouched = nodeAtPoint(location)

        //Detect if the ball is touched
        if(nodeTouched == ball){
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I put the variable ball outside didMoveToView, there is an issue. Issue says ''Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'SKNode'. ''